# Assign the result of a serialization to a variable

Tags: java, serialization

I have an object that I would like to serialize. The thing is, I don't want to send this in a FileOutputStream or ObjectOutputStream. Instead, I want to assign the result to a variable. I cannot find any information on doing this on the web. Is this because there is no standard Java method for doing this? If thats the case, what am I going to need to look into to write up one a method that does this myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you need to do something like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
oos.writeObject(someObject);
oos.close();
byte[] serialized = bos.toByteArray();
```

This will put the byte representation of the serialized object into `serialized`.  You can reverse the process (deserialize) using ByteArrayInputStream and ObjectInputStream.

Note: you can't avoid using ObjectOutputStream ... because *that* is what does all the work of serialization.